# Search a list of comma separated strings on elasticsearch

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch

I have elasticsearch configured for my django project.
Elasticsearch index has two fields user_id and address, my goal is to search a list of comma separated addresses on elasticsearch.

Example:

i have this list of addresses ["abc", "def","ghi","jkl","mno"] and i want to search them on elasticsearch in one hit, the result i'm expecting for the above list is ["abc", "def","ghi"] if these three addresses "abc", "def" and "ghi" (individually) exist on elasticsearch in address field.

Comment: please remember to vote up the answer if it was useful

Comment: @llermaly sorry it doesn't let me upvote because of low rapotation, thank you for the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ingest data

```
POST test_foki/_doc
{
  "user_id": 1,
  "address": "abc"
}

POST test_foki/_doc
{
  "user_id": 2,
  "address": "def"
}

POST test_foki/_doc
{
  "user_id": 3,
  "address": "ghi"
}
```

If you want to do exact matches then you can use a [terms query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html) to filter up by an array of addresses.

**Request**

We use filter because we dont care about score on exact matches (it matches or not)

```
POST test_foki/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "address.keyword": [
              "abc",
              "def",
              "ghi",
              "jkl",
              "mno"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Response**

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 3,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "test_foki",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "YzkL4HcBv0SJscHMrZB8",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "user_id" : 1,
          "address" : "abc"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "test_foki",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "ZDkL4HcBv0SJscHMsZAx",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "user_id" : 2,
          "address" : "def"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "test_foki",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "ZTkL4HcBv0SJscHMtpAd",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "user_id" : 3,
          "address" : "ghi"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

If you want to do full text searches you will have to do a [boolean query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html)

```
POST test_foki/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "address": "abc"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "address": "def"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "address": "ghi"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "address": "jkl"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "address": "mno"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This produces the same Lucene query `address:abc address:def address:ghi address:jkl address:mno`

```
POST test_foki/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "address": "abc def ghi jkl mno"
    }
  }
}
```